# Image-Button coordinates are busted

Tags: libgdx

I have an image-button and I set its position in `create` in this way:

```
imageButton.setPosition(orthographicCamera.position.x+150,150);
```

The problem is that the position always changes, despite I set it in `create`.
Also if I change device, I notice that the coordinates are busted, wrong, instead other views are right.

If I write `setPosition`in `render`, the image-button is faster than the camera, it gets away from the screen, but for other views, this doesn't happen because they follow the camera. Why?

Comment: Do you want it to follow the camera or be static?

Comment: @Charanor follow the camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several possible solutions to this.

---

Try using stage coordinates instead like so: `button.setPosition(150, 150)`. Stage always start at `(0, 0)` bottom left corner.

---

Use 2 separate cameras for your UI and your game.

```
OrthographicCamera gameCam = ...;
OrthographicCamera stageCam = ...;
Viewport viewport = new FitViewport(1280, 720, stageCam); //Constant viewport size
Stage stage = new Stage(viewport);
```

Then use `gameCam` for all of your game related stuff and use `stageCam` for your UI. I use a `FitViewport` here for our stage's viewport since it preserves aspect ratio. Makse sure to read up on [Viewports](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) to more clearly understand what viewport fits your need.

Comment: getX()? There isn't getX();

Comment: @Curio my bad, it should just be 150.

Comment: If I change the device, it changes the position, like before

Comment: @Curio could you provide some screenshots? This is probably because the viewport sizes are different but I need to see to be sure. I've also updated my answer with a potential solution (see `stageCam`).

Comment: I don't know if I can take some screenshots at the moment, but I can tell you that the image-button changes position but other views not.

Comment: Stage stage = new Stage(stageCam, ...); What do I have to put instead of "..."?

Comment: @Curio turns out I messed up again! The Stage actually takes a [Viewport](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Viewports) as its parameter, not a camera. The Stage then uses the viewport's camera as its own camera. See my updated answer.

Comment: The position changes if I change the device, how can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using a viewport with a static aspect ratio (`FitViewport` or `ExtendViewport`)? Do the devices have the same aspect ratio? Pictures would be greatly appreciated as well.

Comment: I'm using your code

Comment: Then the only explanation I can give is that your devices have different aspect ratios. Try changing your viewport to `ExtendViewport`. What is the screen resolution of your different devices?

Comment: One is 320x480, one 1080x1920

Comment: There we have it. They have different aspect ratios. One is 16:9 and the other is 3:2. They won't match up. You have to use different viewports with different aspect ratios depending on the aspect ratio of the devices.

Comment: Ok, so I have to make viewport for each type of screen. But why doesn't the ortographic camera have to do this?

Comment: Yes, one for each aspect ratio. The cameras also have a viewport themselves so you need to change all of the cameras as well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/60997/discussion-between-curio-and-charanor).

Comment: If I have to change the positions of the image-buttons for each screen, so I can use the camera of the game. I notice that the position is the same using it, I only have to resize the images.